# Bad sectors on Disk

Tags: linux

There are multiple bad sectors on my Hard disk, as the message is shown. I want to reinstall OS on the disk.
Is it possible to do the same. If yes whats the process which needs to be followed.

Comment: You can reinstall the OS, but that really has no relationship to bad sectors.  If there are a lot of physical bad sectors, particularly if you are discovering new ones, that's a sign that the drive is dying and you should look at replacing it.  Reinstalling the OS won't help.  If the problems are just data corruption, that can be fixed and reinstalling the OS isn't necessary.  If the OS has been corrupted, it can often be repaired more benignly than reinstalling it.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Still I want to know, Is there not any way to point to the bad sectors and not write do it. Means can't we ignore the bad sectors.

Comment: The system does that for you when it finds them, or you can run chkdsk /r and it will explicitly search for them and lock them out  (it will run at next boot; it can take several hours and should not be interrupted).  The issue is that one way drives fail is progressive failure of the media.  When you start seeing new bad sectors on a recurring basis, the drive is in the process of failing.  It will run out of spare sectors for remapping the bad areas.

Comment: Thanks. I got it, it's better to repair the disk instead of reinstalling it.

Comment: @fixer he's running linux not windows so it should be `fsck` not `chkdsk`

Comment: @DavidPostill: Good catch, missed that.